# Can this solution be generated with a case..when?

Tags: sql

Write a query that appends strings to selected fields, indicating whether or not a specified salesman was matched to a customer in his city?

```
 salesman_id |    name    |   city   | commission 
 -------------+------------+----------+------------
    5001 | James Hoog | New York |       0.15
    5002 | Nail Knite | Paris    |       0.13
    5005 | Pit Alex   | London   |       0.11
    5006 | Mc Lyon    | Paris    |       0.14
    5007 | Paul Adam  | Rome     |       0.13
    5003 | Lauson Hen | San Jose |       0.12


  customer_id |   cust_name    |    city    | grade | salesman_id 
 -------------+----------------+------------+-------+-------------
    3002 | Nick Rimando   | New York   |   100 |        5001
    3007 | Brad Davis     | New York   |   200 |        5001
    3005 | Graham Zusi    | California |   200 |        5002
    3008 | Julian Green   | London     |   300 |        5002
    3004 | Fabian Johnson | Paris      |   300 |        5006
    3009 | Geoff Cameron  | Berlin     |   100 |        5003
    3003 | Jozy Altidor   | Moscow     |   200 |        5007
    3001 | Brad Guzan     | London     |       |        5005
```

This is the solution provided.

```
 SELECT a.salesman_id, name, a.city, 'MATCHED'
 FROM salesman a, customer b
 WHERE a.city = b.city
 UNION
 (SELECT salesman_id, name, city, 'NO MATCH'
 FROM salesman
 WHERE NOT city = ANY
(SELECT city
    FROM customer))
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

This is a solution I thought out and I'm wondering if it will work the same way as the one provided.

```
  Select s.salesman_id, name, city,
  case when s.city = c.city then 'Matched'
  else 'No Match'
  end as City_Match
  from salesman s
  join customer c
  on s.salesman_id = c.salesman_id;
```

Expected outcome.

```
 salesman_id    name        city        ?column?
 5005       Pit Alex    London      MATCHED
 5007       Paul Adam   Rome        NO MATCH
 5002       Nail Knite  Paris       MATCHED
 5006       Mc Lyon     Paris       MATCHED
 5003       Lauson Hen  San Jose    NO MATCH
 5001       James Hoog  New York    MATCHED
```

Comment: those two queries are not identical. at least because they have different join keys

Comment: What is the actual question? If you have two queries, run them and compare the results.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel the results might be the same, that doesn't mean the queries are the same too

Comment: That's why I'm asking for the actual question. Is it "which query is more efficient memory wise?", "which is faster?", or "do they have the same execution plan?" . The point why the OP exists is unclear for me.

Comment: Looks like salesman_id is not used in provided solution, but is used in the replacement. This will likely result in different output. Should salesman_id be used ?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel he asks if the queries do the same thing. what's unclear here?

Comment: The first query is looking (in the second part) for any salesman that is in a city that has no customers. You query is looking for cases where the salesman's city matches the customer's city.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Basically what i'm asking here as an obvious SQL novice is: are the two queries interchangeable? and if not, can mine be altered to produce the solution provided? or is the solution provided the best way to go about it.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exists` with a subquery:

```
select s.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from customer c
                          where c.salesman_id = s.salesman_id and
                                c.city = s.city
                         )
             then 'MATCHED' else 'NO MATCH'
        end) as flag
from salesman s;
```

The sample query you provide is a **joke**.  It has to be:

- It uses meaningless table aliases.
- It uses archaic comma syntax instead of proper, explicit, **standard** `join` syntax.
- It relies on `union` to remove duplicates, when that is unnecessary overhead.
- It uses many more operations than necessary for the logic you want.

Comment: Thanks. found it on a tutorial website that i am using to prepare for an interview, i would rather use join syntax too. Thats the syntax i have become accustomed to since i started learning.

Answer (score 1):

The first query is looking (in the second part) for any salesman that is in a city that has no customers. You query is looking for cases where the salesman's city matches the customer's city.

The equivalent query using a left join and a case statement would be

```
Select distinct s.salesman_id, name, city,
    case when c.city is not null then 'Match' else 'No Match' end as City_Match
from salesman s
left join customer c on s.city = c.city;
```